# How to prevent TypeScript code blocks from being compiled by the Angular AOT Webpack plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I want to exclude some code from being compiled by Angular's AOT compiler. For example, the [webpack-strip-block](https://github.com/jballant/webpack-strip-block) loader can be used to remove code between comments in production.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    /* develblock:start */
    alert("Show in development only"); // Oops. This still appears in production.
    /* develblock:end */
  }
}
```

More specifically, I'm trying to exclude an entire NgModule (e.g. TestModule) from being compiled. One way to do this would be to remove the line(s) in the app-routing.module that create the route. For example:

```
// app-routing.module
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    /* develblock:start */
    path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule'
    /* develblock:end */
 }
]

// webpack.config.js 
{
    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
    use: [
      { loader: '@ngtools/webpack' },
      { loader: 'webpack-strip-block' }
    ]
}
```

Note: This isn't a specific question about the [webpack-strip-block](https://github.com/jballant/webpack-strip-block) plugin. I'm just using the plugin as an example because it makes my intent clear. The plugin's author has [already stated](https://github.com/jballant/webpack-strip-block/issues/9#issuecomment-345100909) that he doesn't expect the plugin to work with the AngularCompilerPlugin. The plugin *does* work with my CSS files, but that's beside the point.

Here are some other things that I've tried:

**1. Using Webpack exclude (or include).** Nope. Excluding the folder throws compiler errors because the application code still depends on TestModule.

```
{
  test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
  loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
  exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/test')
},
```

**2. Using NODE_ENV to conditionally load the route.** Nope. Compiler errors galore because an if statement is (obviously) not allowed inside an array of objects.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule'
  }
}];
```

**3. Using [Webpack Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).** I've tried it, but it doesn't seem appropriate for this use case.

Here's my dependency list:

Angular 6.1.7
TypeScript 2.9.2
Webpack 4.19.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to create a global replacement for var NODE_ENV (for example):

```ts
// inside webpack.config
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
]
```

Then you can use this var like this:

```ts
declare const NODE_ENV: string;

if (NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    routes.push({ path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule' });
}
```

Webpack will replace NODE_ENV with the actual value. In production it will be `'production'` so the code inside the `if ('production' !== 'production')` will be unreachable and AOT will remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using DefinePlugin to set an ENV variable is no longer needed in Webpack 4 (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2537#issuecomment-369129702). I want to leave the question open since I'm still hoping for a more generic solution, but your answer helped me find a solution for the routing module, so I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

In Webpack 4 you can conditionally add a route in app-routing.module using NODE_ENV:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  routes.push({ path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule' });
}
```

This prevents TestModule from being compiled in production. Thanks to Pavel Agarkov for the suggestion to push the route object onto the array.